# What is the Bayesian distribution of two p.d.f's?

Tags: python, bayesian

I whant to make this:

[image]

Theese are the inputs
[image]

I'm traying to replicate this for my app, but don't know how its done.

As you can see, there must be a preset value for the sigma with the inputs of type of game, format of game and stake, that with the mean value of bb/!00 can give the blue p.d.f. The red p.d.f. one can be a preset mean malue for all the players with those inputs, but don't know how to do the green one (bayessian).

How can I paint the green bayessian with those inputs?

How do I get the hight of the bayessian and the p.d.f's?

This is the code I think I'm going to use for the p.d.f's (or similar)

```
    import math  

import numpy
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
############################################################### mu es el valor medio y sigma standard desv

#################################################################
def normal_pdf(x, mu=7, sigma=152):
    sqrt_two_pi = math.sqrt(math.pi * 2)
    return math.exp(-(x - mu) ** 2 / 2 / sigma ** 2) / (sqrt_two_pi * sigma)
x1= pd.DataFrame(numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.1))
y1= pd.DataFrame(map(normal_pdf, numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)))
#df = pd.DataFrame[x1,y1]
#print(df)
print(x1)
print(y1)
x1max=x1.max()
y1max=y1.max()
print("maxx",x1max)
print("maxy",y1max)
#Figure=px.scatter(x=x1, y=y1, data_frame=df)
x11=np.array(x1).squeeze()
y11=np.array(y1).squeeze()
print(x11)
print(y11)
    

fig=go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x11, y=y11))
```

but don't know how to do the bayessian. How can I make it?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Your question is not clear: what is your input data? do you have some code? Are you trying to reproduce exactly this graph? Also in general there's no way to know what these curves represent just from the graph.

Comment: @Erwan just made a modification

Comment: It's better but still not completely clear to me: so the blue curve would be the distribution of some value for a specific player, the red one would be the same value across all players? And by bayesian you probably mean 'posterior distribution', but based on what? I suspect that something is supposed to be the prior but it's not clear.

Comment: yes! the bayesian is something I don't know how or what freccuencies obtain... that's what I'm asking for ... don't know how to obtain the blue one ... I hoped this was a typicall problem .... or something I could easilly obtain ... I will share the link of the app to see if you can help. https://whatsmywinrate.com/